# Is the word "throwee" acceptable?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, nouns, is-it-a-word, er-ee

I wanted to have a word to refer to the thing being thrown, so I decided to use the word "throwee". I can't find this word in online dictionaries, so I guess this word does not exist in the English language.

However, I really like this word and I would like to continue using it in my written communication. I'm not a native speaker, but from my experience with the language, "xee" means "object/person being xed" (where "x" is a verb, e.g. "employee" - "person being employed").

So, what do you think? Is the word "throwee" acceptable? Is it OK if I continue to use it? Should I use a different word?

---

To provide context, I'm a JavaScript programmer. In the JavaScript programming language, there exists a `throw` statement, which throws values of various types (e.g. strings, numbers, objects).

```
// code examples
throw 123;
throw "Invalid argument";
throw new Error;
```

An usage example would be:

> If the throwee is a *Number* value, then... .

which is more terse and IMO more readable than:

> If the value being thrown is a *Number* value, then...

Comment: In my opinion, "the value being thrown" is much more readable than "the throwee".  I'd recommend avoiding it.

Comment: Not the computer meaning: in common English there is "projectile" ... *an object propelled through the air, esp. one thrown as a weapon*.

Comment: "If the projectile is a *Number* value, then...". I like that. `:P`

Comment: For an insightful analysis of current usage of the _-ee_ suffix, check out http://semarch.linguistics.fas.nyu.edu/barker/Research/barker.ee.pdf

Comment: I saw "throwee", and thought "the person having something thrown to them". I wouldn't understand it to mean what you want it to mean.

Comment: `throw` in Javascript creates an *exception*. You should say "If the exception is of type *Number*, then..."

Comment: "Throwee" intuitively means "a person something is thrown to" to me as well. For your sentence, I would use "If the *thrown value* is..." I think that's the tersest way to do it.

Comment: @alcas Yes, I decided to use that term. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither the OED nor the Corpus of Contemporary American English nor the British National Corpus has any record of *throwee*, but a Google search produces some 40,700 pages containing it. Use it only if you think your intended readers will understand it. Many general readers, I suspect, would not.

Comment: *Throwee* (also spelled *throwie*) in urban slang means a type of graffiti art, simple in form but more complex than a tag. Many of the Google results may have to do with this usage. Take the same search to Google Image Search for examples.

Comment: 40k pages is also next to nothing.  In comparison, the programming-specific term `println` has 22 million pages.

Answer (score 15):

In the context of programming languages, you are referring to an [Exception](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_throw.asp). "Exception" is a widely-understood term; "throwee" is unacceptable as a synonym.

If you are concerned that it's still not clear enough, "Exception object" or "thrown object" is unmistakably clear.

Comment: In some other programming language, that would be true. However, JavaScript's `throw` statement allows *any* value as its operand, including primitive values (like strings, and numbers), and non-error objects (objects that cannot be referred to as errors or exceptions). This is the reason why I decided to use the word "throwee" in the first place.

Comment: It's still called an exception in Javascript; for example the page I link to uses it exactly as you want to use it.

Comment: +1 for "thrown object". That works in programming languages and in the physical world.

Comment: @TecBrat "Thrown object" does *not* work in JavaScript, however, since the thrown value can be a primitive (non-object) value.

Comment: @tenfour Yes, you are correct. The term "exception" does refer to the thrown value.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas In Javascript, primitives _are_ objects: `z = 1; z.toString()`, So "thrown object" is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Izkata: that's not technically true; there is a clear distinction between primitives and objects. However in the spirit of general programming jargon, I agree it would be safe to say "object" even in this case.

Comment: @Izkata That is not correct.

Comment: @tenfour I'm sorry if I'm being overly (and possible annoyingly) pedantic here, but it would certainly *not* be save to do that. The ECMAScript standard (which is the *de facto* JavaScript standard) clearly defines an "object" as ["a member of the type Object"](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.3). In the statement `throw 1;`, for example, `1` is interpreted as a *NumericLiteral* (according to the lexical grammar of the language). Such *NumericLiterals*  are evaluated into *Number* values (values of the type *Number*). A *Number* value is clearly not an object.

Comment: I would say "thrown exception" or "exception thrown". "Exception object" doesn't clarify, since exceptions are normally objects.

Answer (score 8):

To me, *throwee* sounds like the opponent of somebody demonstrating a martial-arts move, or maybe the height-challenged participant in a dwarf-tossing competition.

More precisely, I believe the suffix *-ee* is almost always used for people. For example, we use the word *kidnappee* when talking about kidnapped people, but there is no corresponding word **stealee* when talking about stolen property. I would recommend against using the word *throwee* in this context.

Comment: Chris Barker, an excellent semanticist, looked into the semantics of _-ee_ nominals.  He confirms your hunch about animacy, as well as reporting several other findings.  http://semarch.linguistics.fas.nyu.edu/barker/Research/barker.ee.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple contexts here that I will try to answer.

- programming: 'throwing' is essentially an 'exception' process. The target of a thrown exception is either

  - a **catch block** (if you are referring specifically to Java like exceptions
  - an **exception handler** (for the generic concept of code or a process that receives/catches/handles something that is 'thrown'.
- the action of throwing with the arm

  - **receiver** or **target** is where the thrown object is intended, the first is active, the second passive
  - *throwee* is a questionably legal creation with the '-ee' suffix. It's not unpopular, people will know what you mean, it's not at all technical, and it is very informal.

Comment: Yea, based on the responses here, I decided to not use "throwee". I think I'll use the terms "thrown value" or "exception value" in the future. (E.g. "If the thrown value is a *Number* value,...", or just "If a *Number* value is thrown, ...".)

Answer (score 2):

*Throwee* may be a very useful word for a midget-throwing contest.

Other than that, *-ee* should be restricted to people only.

Answer (score 2):

Even if programmers will recognize "throwee" and, after a moment's reflection, realize that it refers to what is being thrown and *not* the code which is doing the catching, it's nonstandard and therefore awkward.  *You* may prefer the short form, but you don't have to puzzle out what it means when you read it; anyone who does will prefer the long form (and that will be the majority of your readers who read it the first time).

Brevity does have its appeal, though.  So use alternate phrasing instead:

> If a *Number* value is thrown, then ...

(And is "value" really adding anything to that sentence?  Are there any non-value *Number*s?)

Comment: Yes, there are `:)`. The term "Number" is ambiguous since it can refer to both a primitive *Number* value, and a *Number* object (an instance of the *Number* "class"). It is for this reason, that the ECMAScript standard (the specification for the JavaScript programming language) defines the term ["Number value"](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19). Note, though, that this applies only to the upper-cased term. The lower-cased term "number" can be used alone, and it is used as an informal synonym for the term "Number value". However, I prefer to be formal in my writing `:)`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas English has a fine word for the ugly “number value”: *numeric* value.

Comment: @tchrist The term "Number value" (notice the capitalization) is an official term defined in the JavaScript language standard. (Follow the link in my comment above.) In the context of JavaScript, "Number value" should be preferred over "numeric value".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `projectile` or `missile` in the general case, but of course in the case of exception throwing this isn't appropriate. At our codeshop we talk about 'the thrown exception'.